# Fade transition

Tags: html, css, transition, fade

I am looking to create a photographic website which has a background image that changes every few seconds.  I have the images changing by using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            var imageID=0;
            function changeimage(every_seconds){
     //change the image
            if(!imageID){
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="John%20Gallacher%20Photography/images/composite/Composite%201.jpg";
            imageID++;
            }
            else{if(imageID==1){
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="John%20Gallacher%20Photography/images/composite/Composite%202.jpg";
            imageID++;
            }
            else{if(imageID==2){
            document.getElementById("myimage").src="John%20Gallacher%20Photography/images/composite/Composite%203.jpg";
            imageID=0;
            }
            }
            }
             //call same function again for x of seconds
            setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*5000));
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload='changeimage(2)'>
    <div>
        <img id="myimage" src="John%20Gallacher%20Photography/images/composite/Composite%201.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to make the images fade in and then out again, and if so what would be the easiest way to do this.  I have a basic understanding of html and css, my javascript is very basic.  Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a slideshow?

Comment: http://wowslider.com/slideshow-maker-software-surface-blur-demo.html

Comment: @mplungjan wowslider is premiuim.

Comment: "WOW Slider is free for non-commercial use."

Answer (score 1):

What is the support list? If you're not worried about older IE, then you can go with CSS Transitions for the transition and change the state with js
http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/MYKFT/

```
#myimage {
  -webkit-transition:all 1s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition:all 1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition:all 1s linear 0s;
  transition:all 1s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Fixes trails in Chrome */
}
```

And then just use js to change the opacity, then image, the opacity...

```
var imageID = 0,
        ti = document.getElementById("myimage");;
var changeImage = function(t){
    // change the opacity of the image to 0, let the css control the animation
    ti.style.opacity = "0.0";
    ti.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=00)'; // IE fallback
    // after 1 second (the animation), change the image
    setTimeout(function(){
        //change the image
        switch(imageID){
            case 0:
                ti.src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTM7c8EFwQ_PseqOEblAtm9qXali9kzvBKsmrGDECLYu1HJP3EO";
            break;
            case 1:
                ti.src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2317326635/3kglmsqti3msjlb1nr60.png";
            break;
            case 2:
                // return to the original image
                ti.src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/FPO_mark3.jpg";
            break;
            default:
                // do nothing
        }
        if(imageID == 2){
            imageID = 0;
        } else {
            imageID++;
        }
        // change the opacity of the image to 0, let the css control the animation
        ti.style.opacity = "1.0";
        ti.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)'; // IE fallback  
    },1000);
} // close changeimage
//call same function again for x of seconds
window.setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks.  I'm not too worried about older IE.  If my understanding is correct unsupported browsers will simply display the first image then not change.  which is fine by me.  Thanks for your very detailed explanation its really helps me understand how you did this.

Comment: Yer welcome. Browsers that don't support CSS Transitions wouldn't animate the opacity. They would just switch the src attribute for the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This has a number of transitions including `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Apply those functions to your images like this:

`$("#image_id").fadeIn();` `$("#image_id").fadeOut();`

But firstly in your head you need to include jQuery. You can do that like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

The `#image_id` is the `id=` of the `<img>` in your HTML Markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple plugin for that, like [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). The code should look like this:

```
<head>
...
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
...
</head>
...
    <div class="fader">
         <img src="image1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
         <img src="image2.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
         <img src="image3.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
...
    <script>
        $('.fader').cycle();
    </script>
</body>
```

Where you shoud replace '/js' with the path to that files (that you should download).

Answer (score 0):

I think a plugin is a lot of overhead for something that you can do with a little code.

I set up a quick example for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/XcBTx/1/

A few remarks:
 - I chose to work with background images, as I believe a background is what you are after, and you would not want the picture to show up on print. You could argue that for a photography website the background image is actual content, but changing the code to work with images in stead should be easy.
 - Note that I use 2 div's for the images, so I can fade one in and one out. Perhaps it would be better to add the second one with javascript to avoid unnessacary markup. The first div I would keep, cause you want users without javascript to see at least one photo. You could consider setting it on the body, but again, I leave that up to you.
 - It will be probably nessacary to preload the images, and wait for them to be loaded before you start the slideshow. Should not be to hard, plenty of information out there.

And the javascript (to be put in the `$(window).load` handler):

```
// the list of background images
var myImages = ['http://placekitten.com/900/400','http://placekitten.com/550/600'];
// the transition speed
var fadeSpeed = 500;
// the time between transitions
var playSpeed = 2000;

function fadeToNextImage() {
    // -- prepare some vars
    // the image wrappers
    var $bg1 = $('#bg1');
    var $bg2 = $('#bg2');
    // the index of the next image in our array
    var nextNr = parseInt($bg1.data('number')) + 1;
    // if the index is larger then the number of images,
    // we want the first image
    if (nextNr > myImages.length - 1) { nextNr = 0; }
    // the path to the next image
    var nextImg = 'url(' + myImages[nextNr] + ')';

    // set the image as background on bg2
    $bg2.css('background-image', nextImg);
    // fade out bg1
    $bg1.fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
    // fade in bg2
    $bg2.fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
        // when the cross fade is ready
        // set the image as background on bg1
        $bg1.css('background-image', nextImg);
        // update the number attribute
        $bg1.data('number', nextNr);
        // show bg1 (which now contains the same image as bg2)
        $bg1.show();
        // hide bg2 (to prepare it for the next slide)
        $bg2.hide();
    });
}

// start the slideshow
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {fadeToNextImage();}, playSpeed + fadeSpeed);
```

I put plenty of comments in there, but feel free to ask!